# Asynctask java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception during file upload

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception during file upload test of my application. It's very strange and occurred only in some of the the Samsung devices (GT 9300).

Here is the traceof asynctask `FileUploadTask`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at npi.comviva.com.race.fragment.FileUpload$FileUploadTask.doInBackground(SourceFile:1021)
at npi.comviva.com.race.fragment.FileUpload$FileUploadTask.doInBackground(SourceFile:950)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Source File(FileUpload.java) lines are :

```
1010:               final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(string));
                    FileUpload.this.uploadTimeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(uploadURL).openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + "*****");
                    final File file = new File(FileUpload.this.rootDir + FileUpload.this.folderName, FileUpload.this.fileName);
                    final FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream(file);
1021                final byte[] array2 = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                    fileInputStream2.read(array2);
                    fileInputStream2.close();
                    fileInputStream.close();
```

Please let me know if any data's are required from my side.

Comment: i think you need to try some another technique

Comment: @madhukar once try by enabling  `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest. once check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. File size will be vary from 10 MB to 50 MB depends on connection(4G,WIFI).  does it matter?

Comment: @Sree Can you please suggest any other technique?. I am calculating file upload bandwidth.

Comment: @user1140237 Thanks for the help. But we are able to capture this type of error only on Samsung device.

Comment: what file type you upload?

Comment: @MinTheinWin It's a file which doesn't have extension.

Comment: what file type( image or audio or zip other )you want to upload?

Comment: It is kind of dummy junk file without having mime type.